# What does equal sign mean in a trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust, syntax, traits

For example in `raw_vec.rs`:

```
pub struct RawVec<T, A: AllocRef = Global> {
    ptr: Unique<T>,
    cap: usize,
    alloc: A,
}
```

I can see `Global` is a struct that implements `AllocRef` trait. If I had to guess it's a way to further constrain the impls that 'A' can take, but then why need 'A' generic type at all? It seems simpler to define the field `alloc` as `Global`.

What does this really mean? I'm surprised I can't find any explanation in Rust books. I appreciate any links to docs on the topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a **default** generic type. It will be used unless you explicitly specify another in the concrete implementation. It's mentioned in the [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#default-generic-type-parameters-and-operator-overloading):

> When we use generic type parameters, we can specify a default concrete
> type for the generic type. This eliminates the need for implementors
> of the trait to specify a concrete type if the default type works. The
> syntax for specifying a default type for a generic type is
> `<PlaceholderType=ConcreteType>` when declaring the generic type.

Comment: Yikes. I missed it. Thanks for the pointer.